# How to deal with Optional[int] in Protocol classes

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing, structural-typing

I have created the following [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) class:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Optional, Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class PipelineProcess(Protocol):

    def update(self):
        ...

    def set_inputs(self, inputs: Dict[str, int]):
        ...

    def get_outputs(self) -> Dict[str, int] | None:
        ...
```

I use it for this example process and others which are built the same way:

```py
@dataclass
class ExampleProcess:
    in_value: Optional[int | None] = None
    out_value: Optional[int | None] = None

    def update(self):
        assert(self.in_value is not None)
        self.out_value = self.in_value * 2

    def set_inputs(self, values: Dict[str, int]):
        assert "value" in values.keys()
        self.in_value = values["value"]

    def get_outputs(self) -> Dict[str, int]:
        return {"value": self.out_value}
```

If I analyze this with `mypy` I got the following error:

```
error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "str": "Optional[int]"; expected "str": "int"
```

To solve this I used `dict[str, Optional[int]]` as the return type of the `get_outputs` method, which seems a bit weird, since I used `Optional` for the dataclass attribute.

**Or** is the `Union` for `Optional` redundant and I have to use `Optional[int]` always instead of `int` because it implicitly says `None` is also valid?

Comment: Yes, this happens because your class field `out_value` might store the value `None` but you advertise the `get_outputs` method to the outside as always returning an `int`, which is violated when the `out_value` is set to None.

Comment: `Optional[T | None]` is pointless because `Optional[T]` already means `Union[T, None]` - [_"`Optional[X]` is equivalent to `X | None` (or `Union[X, None]`)."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

Comment: So the answer is if I use `Optional[T]` I have to use everywhere `Optional[T]` instead of `T`, not only at declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Since `out_value` is declared to be of the union type `int | None`, setting it as value of a dictionary expected to be of type `dict[str, int]` is incorrect. So you need to assure the type checker (and yourself) that by the time you put into it the dictionary `out_value` is in fact an `int`. This can be easily accomplished with an `assert` inside `get_outputs`:

```py
class ExampleProcess:
    in_value: int | None = None
    out_value: int | None = None

    def update(self) -> None:
        assert (self.in_value is not None)
        self.out_value = self.in_value * 2

    def set_inputs(self, values: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        assert "value" in values.keys()
        self.in_value = values["value"]

    def get_outputs(self) -> dict[str, int]:
        assert self.out_value is not None
        return {"value": self.out_value}
```

---

Side note: Contrasting this with the other two `assert` statements in your code, I wonder why you put them there. While `get_outputs` would still work without the additional `assert`, the other two methods would still fail more or less transparently, if you removed the `assert` statements.

`update` would raise `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'` and point to the offending line `self.out_value = self.in_value * 2`.

`set_inputs` would raise `KeyError: 'value'` pointing to `self.in_value = values["value"]`.

But I guess if you wanted to be very explicit or even substitute a custom exception class, you could do it like this:

```py
class ProcessError(Exception):
    pass

class ExampleProcess:
    in_value: int | None = None
    out_value: int | None = None

    def update(self) -> None:
        if self.in_value is None:
            raise ProcessError(
                "Cannot update while `in_value` is None"
            )
        self.out_value = self.in_value * 2

    def set_inputs(self, values: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        try:
            self.in_value = values["value"]
        except KeyError:
            raise ProcessError(
                "Setting inputs requires a dictionary with a `value` key."
            ) from None

    def get_outputs(self) -> dict[str, int]:
        assert self.out_value is not None, "The `out_value` must be set first!"
        return {"value": self.out_value}
```

**EDIT**: Just realized that the first `assert` inside `update` actually does serve the same purpose as the one I suggested for `get_outputs`. Only the second one in `set_inputs` is technically unnecessary.

But there you see that you can assure the static type checker in different ways. One is an `if`-branch based on the type distinction and one is just a straight up assertion.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand what you want to say. My last sentence was created half way through the coding process of my MWE. My misunderstanding was the fact, that `Optional` implicit the `Union`of my choosen type `int` and `None`. The `get_outputs`methods works totaly fine, because the `dict` allows me to extract more than one output. You are right about the `update` method and the missing assert. But for `get_outputs` the assert might be unnecessary because I might want to get outputs, which are `None`.

Comment: @MaKaNu Ah, well, in that case I misunderstood what your intent was. Then yes, the solution is even simpler. Just annotate `get_outputs` with `dict[str, Optional[int]]`. Yes, if your dict values can be either integers or `None`, then you need to annotate this accordingly. Note that `dict[str, int] | None` would be **wrong**. That would imply either a dict with **all** values always being `int` _or_ not a dict at all, but `None`. My explanations regarding the errors are still valid, so I'll leave this post as is.

Comment: Yes, but I like more the guarding assert with specific message, I just did not put them into the MWE. but it's fine to leave the answer.